# Can the locate command be used to find an entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if anyone knew how/if the `/locate` command could be used to find a lost animal with a name. ( Please see my other question for a explanation, if you need one).

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The locate command is for structures, not animals.**

The /locate command was added in Minecraft 1.11 to allow players to locate structures- such as woodland mansions and villages.

If you would like to locate your lost pet, you would have to teleport it to you. Use this command:

```
/tp @e[name=INSERT] @p
```

Replace INSERT with the name of your pet. Type it exactly as you created it, such as PenkatPet or Bob.